# Linux изменить размер файловых систем в LVM

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

```
[root@host2 etc]# df -hT
Filesystem                   Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     devtmpfs  4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        tmpfs     4.9G  4.0K  4.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        tmpfs     4.9G   18M  4.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                        tmpfs     4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/almalinux-root   xfs        70G   17G   54G  23% /
/dev/mapper/almalinux-home   xfs        94G  803M   93G   1% /home
/dev/sda1                    xfs      1014M  264M  751M  26% /boot
tmpfs                        tmpfs     989M   36K  989M   1% /run/user/1000
192.168.203.129:/data/engine nfs4       70G   17G   54G  23% /rhev/data-center/mnt/192.168.203.129:_data_engine

[root@host2 etc]# lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  171G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0  170G  0 part 
├─almalinux-root 253:0    0   70G  0 lvm  /
├─almalinux-swap 253:1    0  6.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─almalinux-home 253:2    0 93.3G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                 11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  


[root@host2 etc]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 171 GiB, 183609851904 bytes, 358612992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0f8a62c3

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   2099199   2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 358612991 356513792  170G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/almalinux-root: 70 GiB, 75161927680 bytes, 
 146800640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/almalinux-swap: 6.7 GiB, 7218397184 bytes, 
14098432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/almalinux-home: 93.3 GiB, 100151590912 bytes, 
195608576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Нужно "оторвать" гигов 50 от /dev/mapper/almalinux-home и присоединить их к 192.168.203.129:/data/engine
Как это можно сделать?

Всё это крутится на одной виртуальной машине.
192.168.203.129:/data/engine - не является удаленным диском. Все на одном диске.

Comment: Ээ, вы хотите объединить локальный диск с сетевым диском? Звучит немножко абсурдно...

Comment: @andreymal дополнил свой вопрос информацией

Comment: «Все на одном диске» — тогда покажите конкретную разметку всех этих разделов на этом самом одном диске, `df` здесь мало чем поможет

Comment: @andreymal добавил lsblk

Comment: `lsblk` не показывает физическое расположение разделов и значит тоже чем мало поможет, интересуют fdisk или gparted [и так далее по списку](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: @andreymal добавил fdisk

Comment: Если всё в LVM — тогда надеемся на появление разбирающихся в LVM (я таковым не являюсь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xfs уменьшаться не умеет. А без уменьшения файловой системы уменьшать блочное устройство не только вредно, но и опасно. Файловую систему придётся пересоздавать.

Поэтому:

- копируете всё нужное из `/home` куда-нибудь на корневой раздел (rsync например в помощь)
- `umount /home`. Если раздел кем-то используется и потому не может быть отмонтирован - решаете эту проблему, затем начинаете сначала
- `lvremove /dev/mapper/almalinux-home`
- `lvresize -L+50G /dev/mapper/almalinux-root`. Это из предположения что nfs у вас почему-то поднят к корневому разделу
- `xfs_growfs /`

Нужно ли восстанавливать `/home` как отдельный раздел - вопрос к вам как администратору. Если не нужно - не забудьте его убрать из `/etc/fstab` и перенести ранее сохранённое содержимое в `/home` теперь на рутовом разделе

Если нужен отдельный `/home` - то `lvcreate -n home -l100%free almalinux` затем `mkfs.xfs` (или другая файловая система по вкусу) и изменить `/etc/fstab` если там был забит UUID для монтирования. Смонтировать и скопировать `/home` обратно.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать